# Where is BLENDER_HOME on Macs?

Tags: installation, osx

Version 2.78 here. I have created a human model in [MakeHuman](http://www.makehuman.org/index.php) and would like to export it into Blender, and then subsequently save the model (after doing some further editing) into a `.blend` file.

According to [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCiIVIB673k&t=611s), I have to download "BlenderTools" from MakeHuman and then copy three directories (`makeclothes`, `maketarget` and `makewalk`) containing scripts into my `$BLENDER_HOME/2.78/scripts` directory.

My question is: I'm on a Mac, so I just have a `Blender.app` that I open from the Spotlight Search. I have no idea where Blender is actually installed on my machine. I tried `which blender` but got nothing.

Any ideas where I can find `$BLENDER_HOME` on my machine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on "Blender.app" and select "Show Package Contents". From there, navigate to the "Contents/Resources" folder and that is `$BLENDER_HOME`.

[EDIT] Actually, what jtheninja said in the comments is probably the more correct way to address the problem. Install in the "~/Library/Application Support/Blender" folder.

Comment: You can also install things for your user at ~/Library/Application Support/Blender (folders here are by version number)

Comment: **Don't modify the application folder** if you can help it! It shouldn't hurt anything, but it's bad form—and people might assume it's deletable, as you can (normally) always download it again. (: